# How to generate an anti forgery token manually in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I need to generate an anti forgery token manually!

How can I generate this?

```
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Generate()
    {
        var token = "";

        //Generate a token

        return Json(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good official overview of the ASP.NET Core antiforgery handling, including an example of the "manual" IAntiforgery functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can inject an `IAntiforgery` instance to your controller ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.iantiforgery)).

```cs
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public TokenController(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Generate()
    {
        var token = "";

        //Generate a token
        var tokenSet = _antiforgery.GetTokens(HttpContext);

        return Json(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the application not accept tokens generated by _antiforgery.GetTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken

Comment: Did you also set the CookieToken to cookies?

Comment: Yes, both the cookie token and the header token are set by sending each request

Comment: I think the RequestToken property is intended to be used as the value of a hidden form field (<input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" [for example] value="…request token…">). At least, that is how some applications use it.