# ASP.Net Core With React Antiforgery token not working

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-apicontroller

I am attempting to develop an application using ASP.NET Core 7 with React, and I need to implement Antiforgery protection for all requests. I have been researching online for a few days and have experimented with various solutions; however, I am still unsure how to resolve the issue.

Below is my code, and I am available to address any additional questions.

**Program.CS**

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(
{
        options.Cookie.Name = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        options.Header = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
});
```

**Controller**

```
[Route("/Test2")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public PostResponse Test2(PostRequest pr)
{
        return RunVehCheck(pr);
}
```

**React (.js)**

```
const getCSRFToken = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7277/Test2", {
            method: "GET"
        });

        const csrfToken = await response.json();
        return csrfToken;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getCSRFToken();
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch("https://localhost:7277/Test2", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-XSRF-TOKEN": getCSRFToken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "vehicleReg": inputValue.current.value
            })
    })
    .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    return res.json()
                } else {
                    throw Error("Erro posting data");
                }
                })
                .then((res) => {
                        console.log("Suucessfully send", res)
                })
                .catch((er) => {
                console.log("Error fetching data", er)
        })
}
```

Comment: the token will be inserted as a hidden field in the form.  You can either send the whole form as a FormData object, (easiest method), or if you send the request as JSON, grab it from the DOM and send it that way. (The hidden field will have a name of "__RequestVerificationToken"... JSON should match)  The cookie is sent automatically.  (There's also no need to set headers...)

Comment: I believe what you are explaining is about MVC and @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). But, in React I am pretty sure I cannot use @Html.AntiForgeryToken().

Comment: You might check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009651/how-to-generate-an-anti-forgery-token-manually-in-asp-net-core  You'd need to call that endpoint each time, and use that in the subsequent fetch/POST as "__RequestVerificationToken"

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these bits to ASP.NET side of things (in startup.cs, ConfigureServices):

```
  services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
  {
      options.HeaderName = "X-Xsrf-Token";
  
  });
```

then (in Configure) :

```
 var antiforgery = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();

 app.Use((context, next) =>
 {
     var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
  // For only one page.  To use on every page just remove the if
     if (string.Equals(requestPath, "/WebAPI/Inventory/EditInventoryItem", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
         context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokenSet.RequestToken!,
             new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
     }

     return next(context);
 });
```

Also see MS docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#generate-antiforgery-tokens-with-iantiforgery-1

My front-end is Angular.  It has a component you can use that reads the value of this cookie, "XSRF-TOKEN", and sets that as a header called "X-Xsrf-Token" on each request.  So you'd have to do the same.  Read the cookie (it's set as HttpOnly: false, so you can do that), and then add a custom header with name of "X-Xsrf-Token".  Don't set the cookie name in antiforgery options.  Let ASP.NET take care of the cookie it uses.  You only need to set the HeaderName to match the header you set from front-end.