# XSRF/CSRF protection in Angular - xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken(); returns null

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, xss

.NET 7 WebAPI + Angular frontend.

Sample response header from API call:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Cache-Control:
no-cache, no-store
Content-Type:
application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Date:
Wed, 08 Nov 2023 16:45:15 GMT
Pragma:
no-cache
Server:
Kestrel
Set-Cookie:
XSRF-TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXX; path=/
Set-Cookie:
XSRF-TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXX; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
X-Frame-Options:
SAMEORIGIN
```

Response Status code: `400 Bad Request`. Of course `XXXXXXXXXXXXX` is actual token.

Request headers:

```
:authority:
localhost:7129
:method:
POST
:path:
/mycontroller/myendpoint
:scheme:
https
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
pl-US,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Content-Length:
11
Content-Type:
application/json
Origin:
http://localhost:4210
Pragma:
no-cache
Referer:
http://localhost:4210/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

As You can see, there is nothing related to XSRF/CSRF protection in request, which is why my endpoint secured with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` is returning `400`

XSRF Interceptor (Angular):

```
@Injectable()
export class XsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private xsrfTokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let xsrfToken = this.xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken();

    if (xsrfToken != null) {
      const authorizedRequest = req.clone({
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfToken)
      });

      return next.handle(authorizedRequest);
    } else {  
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

And in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
  {    
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  },
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: XsrfInterceptor, multi: true }    
],
```

Value of `let xsrfToken = this.xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken();` is `null`

program.cs (backend):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddApplication()
                .AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
var audience = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("FpId");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;
    o.MetadataAddress = $"https://securetoken.google.com/{audience}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    o.Audience = audience;
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MyCors",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute());
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("MyCors");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
var antiforgery = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;

        var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokenSet.RequestToken!,
            new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
   

    return next(context);
});
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Why is that?
My API is "hosted" (locally on my PC) on `https://localhost:7129`, while Angular on `http://127.0.0.1:4210/` - can that be a problem?

Comment: you can't use wildcards for your cors rules when sending credentials.  You need to specify origins, methods and headers explicitly.  You may also want to check my answer here for setting up anti-forgery an Angular:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345191/asp-net-core-with-react-antiforgery-token-not-working/77412445#77412445  Don't set cookie name option in back-end... you can see in the response, it's over-writing the cookie that's mean to be read by Angular for anti-csrf value.

Comment: all I had to do on angular side was "HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      headerName: 'XSRF-TOKEN'
    })" in app.module imports section... and import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http';  cookieName is the name of the cookie you read that's been set by back-end (without http-only set).  headerName is the name of the header that you use to send that value.

Comment: also be aware that you may not be able to read the cookie that backend sets from a different origin... which a localhost with a different port is.  (makes the whole deal hard to debug from ng serve... you need to build and serve from the same origin...)

Comment: also if you use a baseURL, make sure it's relative. The HttpClientXsrfModule won't allow absolute there for some reason.

Comment: it all may be overkill, though.  I think if you require a custom-header on all requests (can be set to anything), you'd be safe from csrf as a pre-flight would be sent.